# Algorithm for Levenshtein distance of multi-dimensional strings

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures

I am looking for an extension for Levenshtein distance (Edit distance) for multi dimensional strings. I am not sure if there is a formal definition for multi dimensional or not, but here is what I am talking about:

**1-D string:** is the regular string

**2-D string:** is something like a list of 1-D strings like

```
dfdsfdsfdsf
dsffgdfdgfdsdaf
dsfdsf
fdgfdgfdg
```

**N-D string:** is list of (N-1)-D strings

How can I calculate the Levenshtein distance between such multidimensional strings?

Comment: Couldn't you just concatenate the strings in the higher "dimensions" to create a 1-D string, and then use the regular Levenshtein distance calculation? Have you tried anything?

Comment: A string, by definition, is one-dimensional. ;-) Consequently, your definition of multidimensional is muddled. 2D, sure, list of strings. 3D? List of list of strings? Unclear. And what should the algorithm calculate for those?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit distance is based on the minimum cost sequence of operations that turns one string into another. If these operations represent rare mistakes then that distance is a rough measure of the probability of one string being corrupted into another.

To find a 2-d variant, you have to decide what sort of operations are permissible, which will depend on why you want to work this out. If each string in one list maps to a corresponding string in the other list, then you might just want the sum of the edit distances in the resulting pairs. If there is no correspondence at all, you might work out the edit distance of all n * m pairs of string and then find the least cost matching which associates one string in the first list with one string in the second list, and scores a matching with the sum of the edit distance of matched pairs of strings. If the corruption process inserts and deletes entire strings, as well as inserting and deleting characters within a string, then you might end up computing the edit distance between all pairs of strings and using these costs to do something like an edit distance calculation between two lists of strings instead of two lists of characters - it all depends on why you want this and what operations might transform one list of strings into another.